# How can I conceal interior camera wiring?

Tags: walls, drill, wire, interior

I'm trying to install 4 cameras, but from other people's place it look not that good that cable can be seen along the wall. is there anyway to hide it? its going to be from left wall to all the way to end of right side of wall and go all the way to ceiling. any ideas?

Comment: Wires...???   That's soooo 2016.

Comment: Have fun replacing batteries, @LeeSam

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Have fun getting a pic during a power outage.

Comment: POE cameras running to a central location with a UPS and only ONE battery to change - done.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  touché

Comment: @Ecnerwal But no drilling, wires, cover boards, painting...

Answer (score 2):

Like any wiring, you need to learn to put it in the walls/ceiling if you don't want to see it.

This generally involves drilling holes in the wall/ceiling at minimum, and may also involve some larger holes and drywall repair. How difficult or easy it is depends on the specific construction details of the building and where you have access.

It almost always involves some amount of surface repair and repainting.

Answer (score 0):

Ecnerwal is right with his answer, but there are also surface-mount cable tracks available at your local big box store. They're not particularly pretty, but they're better than bare cables if you don't want to pull through walls.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Arlo Pro wireless cameras.  They have USB rechargeable batteries.

The cameras connect via your WIFI and can be momitored via your computer or handheld device.

They also have two-way speakers, so you can monitor from anywhere and can listen and speak to someone in the room, if necessary.